How to check the start time of an Android trace after importing it with perfetto?
When I use perfetto to import a trace of an Android phone on my local computer, I want to know when the trace was crawled, so I can confirm the true start time of a segment.
I hope to see the true time format of trace in perfetto, for example: 18:20:35
